# Parallelism with SciPy.optimize

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, thread-safety, scipy

I'm working on some research code which uses `scipy.optimize.leastsq` to optimize a function. It does this about 18 times per iteration, so I would like call leastsq in parallel to reduce running time. This shouldn't be a problem because the optimizations are almost completely separate so very little synchronization is required. I recently found out about `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` which would allow me to do this without having to explicitly set up shared memory (a pain since most of my data are in NumPy arrays). So I made a slight rewrite of my code, hoping it would work, but it throws a strange error: `SystemError: null argument to internal routine`.

The following is a simplification of my code:

```
def optfunc(id):
    def errfunc(x):
        return somedata[id] - somefunc(x)

    lock.acquire()
    x0 = numpy.copy(currentx[id])
    lock.release()

    result = scipy.optimize.leastsq(errfunc, x0)

    lock.acquire()
    currentx[id] = result
    lock.release()

ThreadPool(processes=8).map(optfunc, range(idcount))
```

This should work fine, unless `scipy.optimize.leastsq` isn't threadsafe. So I tried putting a lock around `scipy.optimize.leastsq`; lo and behold it works. However, processor utilization is stuck at 100%, so this is useless to me.

My question is then what can I do about this? I think my options are:

1. Find a thread-safe implementation of LM (levmar, maybe?)
2. Try using processes rather than threads (I don't think this would make a difference)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Windows? There is a known problem with threading in optimize.leastsq on Windows: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1117.

Comment: Hmm, interesting that did not come up when I searched. I'm using Ubuntu but maybe it affects both operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

Using processes instead of threads will make a difference -- it will work whether the program is threadsafe or not. Of course, whether it is faster depends if the time taken in solving the problem is larger than the overhead.

Using processes may require some additional hassle with setting up all necessary data. The `multiprocessing` module however takes care of most of the work, so that shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Answer (score -1):

How many CPUs/cores? There's nothing to be gained if what you have is running at 100% without threading. If `leastq()` is not thread safe, and you're not using a 100% of the computer you have, then you can run one instance of the program per core and have the instances synchronize through the file system.

Comment: There are 8 CPUs on the research machine. I'm not sure why you say nothing would be gained if it's running at 100%. When I tried the example above, the code would run for a bit before throwing the SystemError, and during that time it was hovering around 400% CPU usage. I was thinking about using the solution you proposed but I think it might be more hassle than it's worth at this point. Thank you for your post though.